# Regression or Classification? How to determine sample size?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, sample-size

I have a group of instances with n features (numerical) each.
I am resampling my features every X time steps, so each instance has a set of features at t1:tn. 
The continues respond variable (e.g. with range 50:100) is only measured every X*z times. (e.g. sampling every minute, respond only every 30) The features might change over time. So might the response.

Now at any time point T i want to map a new instance to the respond range.

In case i did not lose you yet :-)
Do you rather see this as a regression or a multi class classification problem (with discretized respond range)?
In either case, is there a rule of thumb how many instances i will need? In case the instances do not follow the same distribution, (e.g. different response for same set of feature values, can i use clustering to filter / analyze this?)

Comment: It depends on the kinds of responds. If only binary responds(e.g. True or False) it's more suitable to treat it as a regression problem. Otherwise treat it as a multi-class classification problem.

Comment: "The continues respond variable (e.g. with range 50:100)"

Comment: Maybe you need something like `Fuzzy Classification` for **continues** respond variable.

Comment: Do the values of the response variable have ordinal properties? I.e. is 51 closer to 50 than 52 is to 50? If so, it's regression. If not, classification.